# What is the role of pytorch dataset.imagefolder's loader option?

Tags: python, pytorch

[Loader option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5eYZ.png)

What is the role of PyTorch dataset.imagefolder's loader option?

Actually, now I have a 10,000 images in a folder, but I want to use only 100 images. Now I load all the image and subset dataset by index.

```
from torch.utils.data import Subset
a = dset.ImageFolder(root=path_F,transform=transform)
index = list(range(0,100))
b = Subset(a,index)
```

Can loader option make my code simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`loader` is responsible for loading the image given path. By default PyTorch uses `pillow` and it's `Image.open(path)` functionality see [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html).

You can specify custom loading like this (load and rotate by `45` degrees):

```
import torchvision
from PIL import Image


def loader(path):
    return Image.open(path).rotate(45)


dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder("images", loader=loader)
```

So no, you shouldn't use it for choosing images.

You could, in principle, use `is_valid_file` argument to do it like this though:

```
class Chooser:
    def __init__(self):
        self._counter = -1

    def __call__(self, path):
        self._counter += 1
        return self._counter < 100


dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder("images", is_valid_file=Chooser())
```

**I would highly discourage this approach though** as the intent isn't immediately clear and it will go through whole dataset checking each image. **Your current way is the way to go**.

Comment: @Hyelin Upvote and accepting an answer is enough here to thank someone. Although nice and appreciated, such comments generate additional noise which doesn't help the site in the long term. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/08/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/) :)